# remove carriage return in bash script, or ignore it when using mv / mkdir

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, line-endings

I am trying to create a directory from a variable that comes from grep'ing and it keeps failing, telling me there is a carriage return where there isn't. I have tried dos2unix, it tells me it is an invalid file. I created the script on ubuntu 10.10 with gedit and unix line endings.

I have also tried piping the output of the cat'd file to

```
tr -d '\r'
```

that doesn't do it.

here is the part of the script which its failing on:

```
ARTIST=`cat read | grep DTITLE | cut -c8- | cut -d"/" -f 1`
ALBUM=`cat read | grep DTITLE | cut -c8- | cut -d"/" -f 2 | awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[\t]+$/,"")};1'`
mkdir $DEST/"$ARTIST"
cd $DEST/"$ARTIST"
mkdir "$ALBUM"
mv $DEST/temp/*.flac $DEST/"$ARTIST"/"$ALBUM"/
```

and the error i receive:

```
mv: target `Hard\r' is not a directory
```

here is the file "read" that it is pulling from:

```
macmini:~/Dropbox/bin$ cat ~/Desktop/temp/read
210 folk 0d021f02 CD database entry follows (until terminating `.')
# xmcd CD database file
#
# Track frame offsets:
#   150
#   13002
#
# Disc length: 545 seconds
#
# Revision: 0
# Processed by: cddbd v1.5.2PL0 Copyright (c) Steve Scherf et al.
# Submitted via: CDex 1.50Beta7
#
DISCID=0d021f02
DTITLE=Cursive / Art is Hard
DYEAR=2003
DGENRE=Indie
TTITLE0=Art is Hard
TTITLE1=Sinner's Serenade
EXTD= YEAR: 2003
EXTT0=
EXTT1=
PLAYORDER=
.
```

i am a little lost at this point. where is the carriage return coming from?

Comment: Are you sure the version of the script you're running is the one you've posted? The error message looks like it comes from a script without double quotes around `$ALBUM` in the argument to `mv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's coming from the read file. Run `dos2unix` on that file.

However, this error message highlights another problem: `mv` is misinterpreting what you're giving it, because what it *thinks* is the target is too short. I'm guessing you aren't quoting file paths containing spaces correctly. Try surrounding the whole argument in double quotes, not merely components of it.

Comment: Yup, always gotta double-quote filename variables in bash.  Common mistake.

Comment: If the script was ran as shown, that's not the problem. `$DEST/"$ARTIST"/"$ALBUM"/` is exactly the same as `$DEST"/$ARTIST/$ALBUM/"`, or as `"$DEST/$ARTIST/$ALBUM/"` if there aren't any special characters in `$DEST`. The error message shows that `$ALBUM` was split and had no `/` after it.

Comment: ah this makes more sense. i was trying to split "artist / album" into a separate variable for both using cut. i thought that was what cut -d"/" -f 2 and cut -d"/" -f 1, cut out everything before and then everything after "/"

Comment: im going to mark this as answered, as running dos2unix on that file resolved the issue. not as elegant as i would like, but i dont know how / why that file has carriage returns, so that will work. if anyone has any idea why it has it, please let me know.

Comment: anyone have any idea why this is inserting carriage returns? i would love to remove dependency on dos2unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one awk script

```
#!/bin/bash   

awk -F"[/=]" 'BEGIN{
    qq="\047"
    DEST="/tmp"
}/DTITLE/{
    ARTIST=$2
    ALBUM=$NF
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"",ALBUM)
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"",ARTIST)
    cmd="mkdir "qq DEST"/"ARTIST qq
    print cmd
    #system(cmd)
    cmd="mkdir -p " qq DEST"/"ARTIST  "/" ALBUM qq
    print cmd
    #system(cmd)
    cmd="mv "DEST"/temp/*.flac " qq DEST"/"ARTIST  "/" ALBUM qq
    print cmd
    #system(cmd)
} ' file
```

To run it, save as a shell script (eg myscript.sh) and type `./myscript.sh` on the command line

Or you can use a programming language that takes care of cumbersome shell quoting issues
eg Ruby(1.9+) script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby  
require 'fileutils'
DEST="/tmp"
File.open("file") do |f|
    while not f.eof?
        line = f.gets.chomp
        if line[/DTITLE/]
            line = line.split(/[\/=]/)
            ARTIST=line[1].strip
            ALBUM=line[2].strip
            Dir.mkdir( File.join(DEST, ARTIST) )
            Dir.mkdir( File.join(DEST, ARTIST, ALBUM) )
            Dir.glob( File.join(DEST, "temp", "*.flac") ).each do |file|
                FileUtils.mv ( file, File.join(DEST, ARTIST, ALBUM) )
            end
        end
    end
end
```

To run it, save as (Eg myscript.rb ) and type `ruby myscript.rb` on the command line or inside a shell script.

Comment: wow, this is great. can't wait to try this tonight. this may be a stupid question, but is there a way to use 2 different interpreters in the same script? i imagine there is not, so should i call this from the other script or should i re-write it in ruby?

Comment: You would be using the shell to execute the scripts. If you want to use the `awk` solution, just copy and paste and save it as a shell script and run as normal. If you decide to use the Ruby one, then use the ruby interpreter to run the script. eg type `ruby myscript.rb` on the command line.